# Pandas - IndexError: tuple index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

The following code in a script:

```
print("cp_name={}, oe_name={}, category={}".format(cp_name, oe_name, category))
print("DF After: mtm={}, tenor={}, limit={}, utilization={}".format(*tuple(ac_df.loc[(ac_df['COUNTERPARTY ID'] == cp_name) & (ac_df['OWN ENTITY ID'] == oe_name) & (ac_df['MEASURE TYPE'] == category)  & (ac_df['TENOR'] == 'Remaining'),['MTM','TENOR', 'LIMIT', 'UTILIZATION']].astype(str).values.flatten())))
```

gave me this error:

```
cp_name=FX_FTA050377_LE, oe_name=BNS, category=FX Notional
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 335, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/lib64/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 52, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/app/ccl/util/pfeweb_command.py", line 288, in handle
    bulk_list, updates = self.proc(file_map, **options)
  File "/app/ccl/counterparty/management/commands/actualexposure_8pm_rpt.py", line 149, in proc
    print("DF After: mtm={}, tenor={}, limit={}, utilization={}".format(*tuple(ac_df.loc[(ac_df['COUNTERPARTY ID'] == cp_name) & (ac_df['OWN ENTITY ID'] == oe_name) & (ac_df['MEASURE TYPE'] == category)  & (ac_df['TENOR'] == 'Remaining'),['MTM','TENOR', 'LIMIT', 'UTILIZATION']].astype(str).values.flatten())))
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

But if I copy the same statement and run it interactively by plugging in the value printed right before it:

```
>>> print("DF After: mtm={}, tenor={}, limit={}, utilization={}".format(*tuple(ac_df.loc[(ac_df['COUNTERPARTY ID'] == 'FX_FTA050377_LE') & (ac_df['OWN ENTITY ID'] == 'BNS') & (ac_df['MEASURE TYPE'] == 'FX Notional')  & (ac_df['TENOR'] == 'Remaining'),['MTM','TENOR', 'LIMIT', 'UTILIZATION']].astype(str).values.flatten())))
DF After: mtm=-13662.69, tenor=Remaining, limit=0.0, utilization=0.0
```

It displayed the message without issue.

What can be the cause of such behavior?

Comment: That's one very long and hard to read line of code.

Comment: Your `cp_name` and/or `oe_name` and/or `category` are not the ones you think they are. Whatever they are. Whatever they are, it looks like there is nothing at their intersection.

Comment: @MikaelÖhman: I did not use soft linebreak to avoid readers think it is the culprit for the error

Comment: @keepAlive I checked the spelling, there is no typo. I don't see quoting issue, either. I added the first print statement just to verify the values of the variables before calling the second print statement which gives error.

Comment: Who spoke about spelling, typo or quoting issue... ? Not me. For one of your lines, the set formed by `(ac_df['COUNTERPARTY ID'] == cp_name) & (ac_df['OWN ENTITY ID'] == oe_name) & (ac_df['MEASURE TYPE'] == category)  & (ac_df['TENOR'] == 'Remaining')` is empty.

Comment: Pardon me and thanks for looking into this. The point I was trying made was that those are the things that could cause values being plugged into second print statement  different from the values displayed in the first statement. But if I just plugged in the 3 values and ran the second print interactively and it showed there was 1 row selected with that condition and the mtm, tenor, limit, utilization values were displayed  without issue.

Comment: I know this is confusing. But, at some point, `ac_df.loc[(ac_df['COUNTERPARTY ID'] == cp_name) & (ac_df['OWN ENTITY ID'] == oe_name) & (ac_df['MEASURE TYPE'] == category)  & (ac_df['TENOR'] == 'Remaining'),['MTM','TENOR', 'LIMIT', 'UTILIZATION']].astype(str).values.flatten()` returns something that has less than 4 elements. Try `'{} {} {} {}'.format(1, 2, 3)`. Your diagnostic is just wrong. *You are NOT copying the same statement*.

Comment: You were right. there was a piece of code in the middle modified the value of TENOR value from Remaining to something else. that was the issue.